# Plugin Facebook para o Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Eu instalei o plugin do facebook no wordpress a alguns meses e ele funcionou corretamente. No entanto, de um mês pra cá, um problema tem atrapalhado meus posts e eu não consigo publicar mais. Ao publicar algo no wordpress e tentar automaticamente postar no facebook, ele gera o seguinte erro:

```
Failed posting to MY NAME Timeline. Error: {"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException"}
```

Alguém tem alguma informação sobre isso?

[Plugin do Facebook para Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/)

Comment: Atualizou o plugin? Ele requer permissões especiais de publicação via Open Graph, o que você precisa liberar no aplicativo, [exemplo](http://prntscr.com/2twmwy).

Comment: Obrigado @VictorMendonça, porém o erro foi sanado sem nenhum ajuste. Acredito que o problema estava no facebook, visto que não atualizei nenhum plugin no wordpress e nem no facebook.

Answer (score 1):

Eu recomendo você criar o seu plugin do facebook no próprio developer do facebook ficaria algo mais ou menos assim

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=seu id";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://seu site/?p=<?php the_ID(); ?>" data-width="692" data-numposts="5" data-colorscheme="light"></div>
```

O código já se explica, width largura data-numposts numero de post etc.. O diferencial dele é o `?p=<?php the_ID(); ?>` depois do link do seu site com isso ele conserta aquele bug de mostrar em todas as páginas os mesmo comentários.

Comment: Grato @lucas-de-souza, porém o erro foi sanado sem nenhum ajuste. Acredito que o problema estava com o facebook, ainda que isso me pareça distante.